# How do you create a form to scan part numbers and auto-populate inventory amount into spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, vba, logging, barcode-scanner, inventory

I am working on a log system for a machine shop and each part has a part number. I am creating an excel spreadsheet to account for the time of checkout, bin location, part #, and check out quantity. I have worked out the kinks to add a time stamp but I am still having issues with figuring out how to auto-populate the part numbers and the quantity of parts checked out (i.e. I checked out 20 ball bearings, part #-50000; check out quantity-20)

I have already done the time stamp using circular reference. My first attempt was trying to use Consolidate and I attempted to do the check out quantity using a `COUNTIFS` formula.

```
[Countifs formula][1]
=COUNTIFS(C:C, C2)
```

I got excel to count the number of parts scanned with the same part #, but when I use the consolidate feature and the statement below pops up. I am unsure what it means. Is there any easier way to scan 20 parts with the same part number so the check out system is similar to a grocery checkout?

[image: Consolidate 1]

[image: Consolidate 2]